# How to decode a text from a charset and convert to another charset in Java?

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, jakarta-mail

I am using the Java mail API to retrieve the emails from gmail via Imap and show it in the Webpage powered with AngularJS.

When I get the data for an email using javax.mail.Message.getContent() return as Object with charset - gb2312.

But my web page is using the UTF-8 charset, so while i am facing strange characters in the web page for some.

I need to convert from gb2312(or any) charset to the utf-8 to show correctly in the webpage.

Can anyone help with this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new String like this and convert it to UTF-8:

```
String s = new String(bytes, "OriginalCharset");
byte[] utfBytes = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

I think Java uses UTF-8 natively, but it's better to do it explicitly.

Comment: Even better to use [StandardCharsets.UTF_8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8) since that doesn't require catching any exception, though I guess you still have to catch because of the original charset.

Comment: Yes, but I wasn't sure whether it was UTF8 or UTF_8 and didn't want to look it up. And note you have to already have the original bytes.

Comment: @Davio

I tried the above the code, but it doesnt work, anything in the below code...


`String mailContent = (String) emailContent;
byte[] utfBytes = mailContent.getBytes("UTF-8");
String output = new String(utfBytes);`

charSet : gb2312

Output :

:阡艋�几�究岸阱岸乃七充允允考耄7867己文崆上上岸朴寒荏峙盅�羌莓州莓州社,
<br/>

Comment: @Davio: *I think Java uses UTF-8 natively* - it uses UTF-16, actually.

Comment: @KarthickT: Java strings are natively UTF-16. But without seeing how the email content is actually encoded (most likely using MIME), or how it is being presented to you, you cannot just blindly convert it to UTF-8 like you have shown.  Chances are, you need to decode it first, such as from base64 or quoted-printable into raw bytes, THEN you can convert those to a String using the appropriate source charset, THEN you can convert that to UTF-8 bytes.

Comment: @Remy : Here the problem the MimeBodyPart.getContent() is returning an object.
From that object i need to extract the data with charset 'gb2312' to a string and convert to utf-8.

It will be helpful if you could say how do we read data from an object to a string with charset.

Comment: @KarthickT: Did you read the documentation? `getContent()` can return a `String`, a `Multipart`, or an `InputStream`. In case of `String` the work is already done. In case of `Multipart`, look at `Multipart.getContentType` and cast `Multipart.getBodyPart()` accordingly. In case of `InputStream`, read it into a `byte[]` array and then convert to `String` using `MimeBodyPart`s charset.